# Remove paint from stained glass windows

Tags: windows, old-house, paint-removal

I have a couple stained glass windows that look to have paint around the outsides from previous owner painting the trim. Any suggestions on removing the paint without damaging or am I out of luck?

[image]

Comment: use a razor blade, or a box cutter blade, to scrape the paint off the glass

Comment: The rough texture of the glass seems to point to a chemical stripper or solvent, as scraping will be difficult. With either chemical or mechanical method I think you should prepare for having to repaint the wood molding, due to there being so much paint so close to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Citristrip often to remove paint from windows after the painters have left. It works on stained glass. You brush it on thin and only have to wait for 10 minutes or so and then wipe it off. Avoid getting it on the trim because it'll remove that paint too. As with all cleaners, try it in a small spot to see how it works.
[image]

Comment: Great answer, Jack!  I've used CitriStrip many times and it's great. Environmentally friendly, yet works great. Like the label says, "no harsh fumes" (true), it smells like oranges or lemons. I know product recommendations are frowned upon here, but this is a great product that deserves recommendation. +

Comment: any citrus based solvent would probably work

Comment: Are you sure that this won't dissolve the putty that helps secure the panes?

Comment: I don't see any external putty, just wood and soldered lead "came". If done properly, the glass panes are *bedded* in a small amount of putty, but that is behind the wood molding.

Answer (score 0):

Although the solvent is a great way of removing the paint, it might have a negative effect on the lead. The putty referred to in the earlier comment is referring to the Leadlight putty that is in the Leadlight. If it is old and no longer waterproof it might soak up the solvent and create an environment that oxidises the lead.

Comment: Do you actually know of such a reaction, or are you speculating?

Comment: Lead is inert in normal conditions, but it is a metal and will oxidise if it is in contact with anything that doesn’t have a neutral pH. That is a fact. So if you are introducing a caustic substance to the lead and it gets into the channel and stays there, the lead will continue to oxidise, making lead dust which is not good to breath. I’m a stained glass worker so I have seen this reaction, it can happen in many different ways. It’s best to make sure your painter masks up the Leadlight and is careful not to get paint everywhere

Comment: Ah. I'd be a bit surprised if paint counted as a caustic material, and further surprised if the paint didn't encapsulate any lead oxide that did arise, but I see the concern.

Comment: The paints isn’t caustic, but the paint remover is